# How to add a minutes column to date column sql

Tags: sql, date, time, amazon-redshift, addition

I may sound silly asking it - but I have the need to add a value derived from one column of database to the other which is the date.

Following is the image of data I have - timeelapsed/60000 gives me the duration of task in minutes and I would require the same to be deducted from the lastupdatedtime to know the time when was the task picked. Please help!

[image]

I have attempted as per your suggestion

lastupdatedtime - (timeelapsed/60000) * interval '1 minute' as task_pick_datetime,

But I see the difference appearing is huge.

For instance, the audited time is 2020-03-12 17:41:39.224, duration in min is 3.06 but the task pick time shows 2020-03-12 12:08:35.417 which is 5 hours difference. Unsure where am I going wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8akWy.png)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Standard SQL (which is the tag on your question), you can use:

```
select lastupdatetime - (timeelapsed/60000) * interval '1 minute' as task_pick_datetime
```

However, date/time functions are notoriously database dependent, so your database may not support this syntax.